# What kind of PSU is this?

Tags: power-supply

I collect PSUs. But one is different compared to all others.

It doesn't have an output voltage written on it. When I measure the output it's 0V DC and also 0V AC. Also I didn't find anything about the output voltage in the [data sheet](http://php2.twinner.com.tw/files/tdcpower/DBEA-11WP.pdf).

So what kind of PSU is this?

(The word "Eingang" on the photo is German and means input.)

[image: photo of PSU]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a power supply, in the sense of what you might generally understand as a power supply, even if this powers a lamp.

It's a ballast for PL type compact fluorescent light tubes with integrated starter. Which actually reads on the device, "FOR: PL 1*11W LAMP".

So technically the output voltage is same as input voltage but with current limiting.

Please note the output is mains-referenced so it is not safe to touch.

If it had no output at all, the fuse may be blown, and depending on which way the unit is plugged to mains outlet, it might have been neutral that directly passes trough the module.

Comment: Why is the lamp not connected to the mains outlet directly?

Comment: Fluorescent tubes can't be connected to mains directly. They would not start up at mains voltages as they require higher strike voltages. It would blow the fuse or explode without current limiting which is done by the inductor. If you look at any standard fluorescent tube light fixture, it has the ballast inductor built-in you might not even notice, an user-exchangeable starter choke which uses the inductor to induce the tube start voltage, and an user-exchange fluorescent tube.